# Add list items letter separator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have i `'asc'` list of names, i'd like to add a letter so it would be look like something like this:

```
<li><a href="#">Abram</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Amanda</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Bernard</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Fox</a></li>
```

to

```
<div>A:</div>
<li><a href="#">Abram</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Amanda</a></li>
<div>B:</div>
<li><a href="#">Bernard</a></li>
<div>F:</div>
<li><a href="#">Fox</a></li>
```

any ideas?

Comment: Yup, I have a few. But what have you tried?

Comment: Assuming this is wrapped in a `<ul>`, that's invalid HTML you want - only `<li>` is a valid child of a `<ul>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using jquery, you can do something like this:

```
var currentLetter, prevLetter = null;
$("li").each(function() {
    currentLetter = $(this).find("a").text()[0];
    if (currentLetter != prevLetter) 
    {
        $("<div>").text(currentLetter).insertBefore($(this));
    }
    prevLetter = currentLetter;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Uw9L4/

Though technically you shouldn't be putting a `div` inside of a `ul` (even though it totally renders fine). I would go with inserting `li` without an anchor to maintain semantics.

Comment: Or inserting ul inside each li like:

`<li>A: <ul><li>Abram</li><li>Amanda</li></ul></li>`